# What is the purpose of VSTS dot net core build task version 2 purpose

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

What is the difference between the version one?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core BUild task (`dotnet build`) only build the specified project and it's dependencies. It not provide converting .ts to .js and js.map (you can refer TypeScript).

More detail about dotnet build, you can refer [dotnet-build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build?tabs=netcore2x).